# Thread safety of C++ on MicroBlaze

Tags: c++, stl, malloc, microblaze

Has any one ever written a multi-threaded C++ application for MicroBlaze? The Xilinx documentation states that:

> The standard C library provided with EDK is not built for a multi-threaded environment. STDIO functions like printf(), scanf() and memory management functions like malloc() and 
>   free() are common examples of functions that are not thread-safe. When using the C library 
>   in a multi-threaded environment, proper mutual exclusion techniques must be used to protect 
>   thread unsafe functions.

Additionally, MicroBlaze GCC reports that the thread model is "single."

If I'm using C++ standard library containers, this is surely unsafe, correct?

I'm having a heck of time even getting an answer to this simple question from Xilinx, let alone a way to fix it. It seems that this is a major deficiency of the Xilinx provided build system.

Comment: Wow, that makes multi-threaded C++ almost unusable on the platform. If you made your own thread-safe memory allocator, hooked `new` and `delete` to it, and made sure code run in any thread but one doesn't touch any code but your own, you could use additional threads for computation/processing purposes. But basically this makes multi-threading almost unusable on the platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer from Xilinx (via email) is below. It makes no mention of multi-threading. It also references a their software tool 8.2i which was released in 2006 (6 years ago!!!). In short, it makes no sense.

Lessons learned:

- Xilinx support is terrible.
- Xilinx software tools are an afterthought for them.
- I can only assume that what is outlined in documentation is correct, specifically that you cannot use dynamic memory allocation in a multi-threaded environment. This means no c++ standard library containers.
- If you're the hardware guy about to select a MicroBlaze soft core processor, check with the firmware guy before you do that. What kind of applications is he expecting to write? Make sure he knows that he can't write a multi-threaded application in C++.

> **malloc()**
>
> Microblaze C library shipped with a small, minimal functionality
>   malloc(). When used, memory could not be freed. Other functions such
>   as calloc, realloc, etc., were not supported. There were also bugs
>   when using both malloc() and routines such as printf, scanf, etc. To
>   fix this, the minimal functionality malloc() has been removed. It has
>   been replaced by original Newlib malloc(). As a result, you should see
>   NO functionality issues. You might see a code size increase of around
>   4K. Because of the differences in which the new full functionality
>   malloc() requests memory, user programs might need to review their
>   heap size settings. If you see your malloc() calls returning NULL,
>   where they used to work, try increasing your heap size. This change
>   was essential to fix broken functionality.
>
> For the rare cases where you still want the original light-weight, but
>   broken malloc() functionality, the source code (malloc.S) can be
>   included as one of the source files to be compiled to build your
>   application. This will retain the old functionality, code size
>   requirements, and dynamic memory requirements seen prior to EDK 8.2i.
>
> **xil_malloc()**
>
> MicroBlaze C library shipped with an alternative implementation of
>   dynamic memory allocation called xil_malloc(). This routine has some
>   limitations; it does not allocate memory from the heap, but rather
>   from a fixed 64K buffer. This routine has now been deprecated. Though
>   this routine is still available for linkage, its use is strongly
>   discouraged. Please use malloc(); it is smaller than xil_malloc() and
>   provides better functionality. When using malloc(), make sure to
>   review your heap size settings to satisfy your dynamic memory
>   requirements.
>
> The standalone BSP contains a parameter "need_xil_malloc". This
>   parameter was intended to allow you to write code that contains
>   malloc(), yet wire it to the xil_malloc() implementation. Due to bugs
>   in the implementation of the parameter and due to the deprecation of
>   xil_malloc(), this parameter is deprecated as well.
>
> Xilkernel contains a parameter "use_xil_malloc". This parameter was
>   intended to allow the kernel message queue implementations to use
>   xil_malloc() instead of malloc(). Due to the deprecation of
>   xil_malloc(), this parameter is deprecated as well.
>
> If you still want xil_malloc() source code for legacy reasons, the
>   "xil_malloc.c" and "xil_sbrk.c" files can be downloaded and used.
>
> **C++ Applications**
>
> Prior to EDK 8.2i C++ applications might exhibit unusual behavior,
>   memory corruption, etc. To fix these issues, include the attached
>   source file (newlib_malloc.c) as part of your application compilation.
>   This will fix the unexplained crashes. This work-around fixes bugs in
>   the malloc() implementation in the MicroBlaze C library. This
>   work-around has been incorporated into the C library starting in EDK
>   8.2i.

This information also appears to be available at: http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/23345.html